# python pandas plot line chart in pandas.plot hbar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a horizontal bar chart created with

```
df.plot(kind='barh', ax=ax)
```

and now I would like to plot a horizontal line chart in the same axis. How can I do that. There seems to be no equivalent lineh

I tried to just flip axes when plotting a regular line

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(k=['A','B','C','D'], v=[1,3,2,3]))
df.plot(x='v', y='k')
```

but then pandas complains that there is no numerical data to plot

Comment: No such option exists for pandas plots. Use matplotlib directly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use matplotlib, you can do like the following. Here the command `xticks()` is to set x-tick labels only at integer values.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(dict(k=['A','B','C','D'], v=[1,3,2,3]))

plt.plot(df.v, df.k)
plt.xticks(range(1, max(df.v)+1))
plt.show()
```

[image]